# slime - Process inferior-lisp segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: emacs, lisp, slime, clisp

Yesterday, I tried slime on my emacs.

After installation and configuration, it works good.

But after some play, today I start it and it throws following error.

I googled but nothing helpful found.

Could anyone give some clue?

OS: centos7
emacs: 24.3
lisp: clisp
slime-mode, slime, slime-company have been installed.

```
(progn (load "/home/angelo/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20150402.908/swank-loader.lisp" :verbose t) (funcall (read-from-string "swank-loader:init")) (funcall (read-from-string "swank:start-server") "/tmp/slime.4512"))

  i i i i i i i       ooooo    o        ooooooo   ooooo   ooooo
  I I I I I I I      8     8   8           8     8     o  8    8
  I  \ `+' /  I      8         8           8     8        8    8
   \  `-+-'  /       8         8           8      ooooo   8oooo
    `-__|__-'        8         8           8           8  8
        |            8     o   8           8     o     8  8
  ------+------       ooooo    8oooooo  ooo8ooo   ooooo   8

Welcome to GNU CLISP 2.49 (2010-07-07) <http://clisp.cons.org/>

Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Michael Stoll 1992, 1993
Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Marcus Daniels 1994-1997
Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Pierpaolo Bernardi, Sam Steingold 1998
Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Sam Steingold 1999-2000
Copyright (c) Sam Steingold, Bruno Haible 2001-2010

Type :h and hit Enter for context help.

[1]> 
;; Loading file /home/angelo/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20150402.908/swank-loader.lisp ...
;; Loaded file /home/angelo/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20150402.908/swank-loader.lisp
;; Loading file /home/angelo/.slime/fasl/2015-04-02/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/backend.fas ...
;; Loaded file /home/angelo/.slime/fasl/2015-04-02/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/backend.fas
;; Loading file /home/angelo/.slime/fasl/2015-04-02/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/xref.fas ...
;; Loaded file /home/angelo/.slime/fasl/2015-04-02/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/xref.fas
;; Loading file /home/angelo/.slime/fasl/2015-04-02/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/metering.fas ...
;; Loaded file /home/angelo/.slime/fasl/2015-04-02/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/metering.fas
;; Loading file /home/angelo/.slime/fasl/2015-04-02/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/clisp.fas ...
WARNING: DEFUN/DEFMACRO: redefining function BREAK in
         /home/angelo/.slime/fasl/2015-04-02/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/clisp.fas,
         was defined in /home/angelo/tools/clisp-2.49/src/condition.fas
WARNING: Replacing method #<STANDARD-METHOD (#<BUILT-IN-CLASS T>)> in
         #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION EMACS-INSPECT>
;; Loaded file /home/angelo/.slime/fasl/2015-04-02/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/clisp.fas
;; Loading file /home/angelo/.slime/fasl/2015-04-02/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/gray.fas ...
WARNING: The generic function
         #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION STREAM-LINE-COLUMN> is being
         modified, but has already been called.
WARNING: The generic function
         #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION STREAM-FORCE-OUTPUT> is being
         modified, but has already been called.
WARNING: The generic function
         #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION STREAM-LINE-COLUMN> is being
         modified, but has already been called.
;; Loaded file /home/angelo/.slime/fasl/2015-04-02/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/gray.fas
;; Loading file /home/angelo/.slime/fasl/2015-04-02/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/match.fas ...
;; Loaded file /home/angelo/.slime/fasl/2015-04-02/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/match.fas
;; Loading file /home/angelo/.slime/fasl/2015-04-02/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/rpc.fas ...
;; Loaded file /home/angelo/.slime/fasl/2015-04-02/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/rpc.fas
;; Loading file /home/angelo/.slime/fasl/2015-04-02/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/swank.fas ...
;; Loaded file /home/angelo/.slime/fasl/2015-04-02/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/swank.fas
;; Swank started at port: 51389.
CL-USER> 
Process inferior-lisp segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Following steps can reproduce the issue:
    1. Install slime and slime-mode
    2. Run M-x slime in emacs
    3. run 'lisp' in slime , (run (+ 2 2) works fine)
    4. Above error will display

Currently my solution is to re-install slime.

Comment: Did reinstalling SLIME fix the problem?